# How do I pass a custom SQL string or parameters to a tableadapter or somesuch in C# / Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datasource, strongly-typed-dataset

What I want to do is create a SQL statement dynamically OR create the WHERE clauses dynamically and pass them to some kind of method which fills a dataset.

In the Visual Studio 2010 'add query' wizard all you can do is explicitly define a hard-coded query that the call will execute.

What I want is something like tableName.get(String sql query). Something like that.

How do I define that, how do I execute my own SQL queries on the datasource?

I'm really lost with this, please ask if you need more information.

Many thanks,
Thomas

xxx

Answer (score 1):

i'm not very sure i completely understand your request, but maybe you can use the "dynamic" keyword instead of original definition. for example:

```
public dynamic mySqlDataAdapter ...; (you can use mySqlDataAdapter with all SqlDataAdapter functions. The syntax isn't verified at design-time.)

public dynamic myDataTable ...;
```

and you can call them:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
```

So you can use any DataAdapter from your DataSet with any DataTable.

For example , I used it in the following situation: I have e base form with methods for saving data, "save_data()" . In one of these methods I have to update the data, so I use:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
```

I use this form as base for other forms for updating data in application.

Further, when I make a form, based on the first form, I call "save_data()" methos, but every form has it's own strongly typed dataadapter and datatable. But with "dynamic keyword" the situation is solved.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really good VB.NET (shudder) example.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/UseParametersinyoursqlcommand.htm

OK, its for an insert statement, but swap that for your select statment.

Plenty of possible arguments that could arise after a good code review, but the point is, it shows how to open a sql connection, create a command on it, set parameters on that command and execute it, with the added bonus of some error handling.

**Edit**
Here's a c# example populating a (shudder) dataset.

[click me](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/FillaDataSet.htm)

Comment: Many thanks. Any way of doing against the strongly typed datasets produced by the wizard and stored in the XSDs though?

Comment: I'm not sure what one of those is.

It sounds like a better bet for you is to use some linq to sql, which will return classes, properties and instances exactly as defined in the db http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/07/01/linq-to-sql-tutorial/

Comment: I'm connecting to an Oracle DB.